# Проблемы с использованием async, await

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, telegram, async-await

Здравствуйте, форумчане))
У меня такой вопрос: написал бота для telegram, который извлекает определенную информацию из фотографии и заносит ее в базу данных. Далее код, после- пояснение.

```
 private static async void BotOnPhotoReceived(object sender, MessageEventArgs messageEventArgs)
    {
        var message = messageEventArgs.Message;
        try
        {
            if (message == null || message.Type != MessageType.PhotoMessage)
                return;


            var fileId = message.Photo[message.Photo.Length - 1].FileId;

            var file = await Bot.GetFileAsync(fileId);

            var stream = file.FileStream;

            using (Stream output = new FileStream($"../../Photo/img{message.Chat.Id}{fileId}.jpg", FileMode.Append))
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[32 * 1024];
                int read;

                while ((read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    output.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
            }

            await Bot.SendChatActionAsync(message.Chat.Id, ChatAction.Typing);

            var FileUrl = @"D:\\128.png";
            using (var streamm = System.IO.File.Open(FileUrl, FileMode.Open))
            {
                FileToSend fts = new FileToSend();
                fts.Content = streamm;
                fts.Filename = FileUrl.Split('\\').Last();
                var test = await Bot.SendStickerAsync(message.Chat.Id, fts);
            }

            string imagePath = $"../../Photo/img{message.Chat.Id}{fileId}.jpg";

            TextDetection newTD = new TextDetection();

            string text = newTD.photo2string(imagePath);

            string result = ParseString(text);
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDouble(result));
            double result1 = Math.Abs(Convert.ToDouble(result));

            DataBaseCon.InsertUser((int)message.Chat.Id, message.Chat.FirstName);
            DataBaseCon.InsertAmount((int)message.Chat.Id, result1);

            var keyboard = new Telegram.Bot.Types.ReplyMarkups.InlineKeyboardMarkup();
            keyboard.InlineKeyboard = new Telegram.Bot.Types.InlineKeyboardButtons.InlineKeyboardButton[][]
            {
                new Telegram.Bot.Types.InlineKeyboardButtons.InlineKeyboardButton[]
                {
                    new KeyboardButton("Продукты питания"),
                    new KeyboardButton("Техника"),
                },
                new Telegram.Bot.Types.InlineKeyboardButtons.InlineKeyboardButton[]
                {
                    new KeyboardButton("Транспорт"),
                    new KeyboardButton("Мобильная связь")
                },
                new Telegram.Bot.Types.InlineKeyboardButtons.InlineKeyboardButton[]
                {
                    new KeyboardButton("Другое")
                },
            };

            await Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id, "Выберите категорию товара, который вы приобрели", replyMarkup: keyboard);


            await Task.Delay(1000);

            bool flag = true;

            Bot.OnCallbackQuery += (object sc, CallbackQueryEventArgs ev) =>
            {
                Task.Delay(5000);
                if (ev.CallbackQuery.Data == "Транспорт" && flag)
                {
                    DataBaseCon.InsertCategory((int)message.Chat.Id, "Транспорт");
                    Bot.AnswerCallbackQueryAsync(ev.CallbackQuery.Id, "Расходы на транспорт зафиксированы");
                    Bot.AnswerCallbackQueryAsync(ev.CallbackQuery.Id);
                }
                else
                if (ev.CallbackQuery.Data == "Мобильная связь" && flag)
                {
                    DataBaseCon.InsertCategory((int)message.Chat.Id, "Мобильная связь");
                    Bot.AnswerCallbackQueryAsync(ev.CallbackQuery.Id, "Расходы на мобильную связь зафиксированы");
                    Bot.AnswerCallbackQueryAsync(ev.CallbackQuery.Id);
                }
                else
                if (ev.CallbackQuery.Data == "Продукты питания" && flag)
                {
                    DataBaseCon.InsertCategory((int)message.Chat.Id, "Продукты питания");
                    Bot.AnswerCallbackQueryAsync(ev.CallbackQuery.Id, "Расходы на продукты питания зафиксированы");
                    Bot.AnswerCallbackQueryAsync(ev.CallbackQuery.Id);

                }
                else
                if (ev.CallbackQuery.Data == "Техника" && flag)
                {
                    DataBaseCon.InsertCategory((int)message.Chat.Id, "Техника");
                    Bot.AnswerCallbackQueryAsync(ev.CallbackQuery.Id, "Расходы на технику зафиксированы");
                    Bot.AnswerCallbackQueryAsync(ev.CallbackQuery.Id);
                }
                else
                if (ev.CallbackQuery.Data == "Другое" && flag)
                {
                    DataBaseCon.InsertCategory((int)message.Chat.Id, "Другое");
                    Bot.AnswerCallbackQueryAsync(ev.CallbackQuery.Id, "Расходы на другую категорию зафиксированы");
                    Bot.AnswerCallbackQueryAsync(ev.CallbackQuery.Id);
                }
                flag = !flag;
            };

            if (flag)
            {  
                await Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id, WalletKeeper.Constants.IT_IS_DONE);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e){
            await Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id, WalletKeeper.Constants.FAILED);            
        }
    }
```

Как видите, я тут использую кнопки и с ними проблема(вернее, с их обработкой).
Я загружаю фотографию, после чего выбираю, в какую категорию внести данные(в БД) "Транспорт", "Мобильная связь" e.t.c. и у меня возникает следующая проблема: допустим, загружаю фото в первый раз и выбираю категорию- все хорошо, во второй раз- тоже информация вводится корректно, а в третий раз у меня одни данные вносятся в БД дважды, уже всю голову сломал(и дебаггер тоже), но баг так и не нашел. Предположительно, проблемы из-за неправильного применения **async & await**. На всякий случай выложу еще код

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Bot.OnMessage += BotOnMessageReceived;
        Bot.OnMessage += BotOnPhotoReceived;

        var me = Bot.GetMeAsync().Result;
        Console.Title = me.Username;

        Bot.StartReceiving();
        Console.ReadLine();
        Bot.StopReceiving();
    }
```

Заранее спасибо))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша ошибка в том, что внутри обработчика `BotOnPhotoReceived` вы каждый раз заново подписываетесь на `OnCallbackQuery`. Таким образом, с каждой новой полученной картинкой, у вас на собитие `OnCallbackQuery` вешается всё больше и больше одинаковых обработчиков. При наступлении события, они все срабатывают поочередно.

Просто вынесите эту часть кода наружу из `BotOnPhotoReceived`.

```
Bot.OnCallbackQuery += (object sc, CallbackQueryEventArgs ev) =>
{
    //...
}
```

---

Сделайте аналогично тому, как вы подписываетесь на `BotOnMessageReceived` и `BotOnPhotoReceived`. То есть весь код из лямбда-выражения поместите в обычный метод, и подпишите его на событие один раз в начале программы. В методе `BotOnPhotoReceived` вообще не трогайте `Bot.OnCallbackQuery` (уберите оттуда все упоминания). Вот приблизительный вид того, что должно получиться:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // ...
    Bot.OnCallbackQuery += BotOnCallbackQuery;
    // ...
}

private static void BotOnCallbackQuery(object sender, CallbackQueryEventArgs ev)
{
    if (ev.CallbackQuery.Data == "Транспорт")
    {
        DataBaseCon.InsertCategory((int)message.Chat.Id, "Транспорт");
        Bot.AnswerCallbackQueryAsync(ev.CallbackQuery.Id, "Расходы на транспорт зафиксированы");
        Bot.AnswerCallbackQueryAsync(ev.CallbackQuery.Id);
    }
    else if (ev.CallbackQuery.Data == "Мобильная связь")
    {
        DataBaseCon.InsertCategory((int)message.Chat.Id, "Мобильная связь");
        Bot.AnswerCallbackQueryAsync(ev.CallbackQuery.Id, "Расходы на мобильную связь зафиксированы");
        Bot.AnswerCallbackQueryAsync(ev.CallbackQuery.Id);
    }
    else if (ev.CallbackQuery.Data == "Продукты питания")
    {
        DataBaseCon.InsertCategory((int)message.Chat.Id, "Продукты питания");
        Bot.AnswerCallbackQueryAsync(ev.CallbackQuery.Id, "Расходы на продукты питания зафиксированы");
        Bot.AnswerCallbackQueryAsync(ev.CallbackQuery.Id);
    }
    else if (ev.CallbackQuery.Data == "Техника")
    {
        DataBaseCon.InsertCategory((int)message.Chat.Id, "Техника");
        Bot.AnswerCallbackQueryAsync(ev.CallbackQuery.Id, "Расходы на технику зафиксированы");
        Bot.AnswerCallbackQueryAsync(ev.CallbackQuery.Id);
    }
    else if (ev.CallbackQuery.Data == "Другое")
    {
        DataBaseCon.InsertCategory((int)message.Chat.Id, "Другое");
        Bot.AnswerCallbackQueryAsync(ev.CallbackQuery.Id, "Расходы на другую категорию зафиксированы");
        Bot.AnswerCallbackQueryAsync(ev.CallbackQuery.Id);
    }
}
```

(Это не готовое решение, а просто пример. Как видите, я убрал из кода переменную `flag` т.к. не понимаю для чего она у вас служит.)

Comment: я не совсем понимаю, как это должно выглядеть?

`Bot.OnCallbackQuery += (object sc, CallbackQueryEventArgs ev) =>
{
     private static async void BotOnPhotoReceived(object sender, MessageEventArgs messageEventArgs)
        {
}
}`

Comment: это так должно выглядеть?

Comment: @AlekseyBrekhin дополнил текст ответа.